# How do I "change gravity"?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I have a mission to "Change gravity 30 times in a single run".  How do I change gravity?  I thought maybe just touching the screen (activating the backpack), but I did that well more than 30 times and didn't get the completion.  Since this is one of those missions that doesn't show progress, I don't even know if I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the gravity, you need to have the **Gravity suit.**  Once you have it, press the screen 30 times (non-consecutive: therefore if you crash, your counter will continue where it left off next time you pick up that vehicle) and you will complete that mission.  To get the Gravity suit, try to obtain the vehicle item in your current run.

> The vehicle pick-up appears as a rainbow block with gears in it.

*From my experience the spawn type has been random*

> When the player touches the screen gravity reverses and Barry walks
> whether on the ceiling or on the ground depending on the direction
> gravity is facing.

[Source of quote and picture](http://www.giantbomb.com/jetpack-joyride/61-36260/)

[image]

Comment: It still counts if you get 17 with the suit, lose it, get it again, and get the last 13. It doesn't have to be with a single suit, just in one run. If you die before getting it, hope for a second chance from the slots, as that will still count also.

Comment: It's totally random what vehicle you get, though if you have the X Ray Specs it's easy to watch for the Gravy Suit. For this mission it's not really necessary to hunt that hard though

Comment: Strangely, I had not seen that suit once up until this point - then as soon as you posted I got it - magic?  Now to practice not dying so much...

Comment: @Fluttershy added in clarification :)